# Preview PDF in ASP .NET without excuting PDF's embedded JS

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have a problem previewing a PDF, I use an `iframe` and when certain PDFs (which have embedded JS) show the print dialog automatically.

Code:

```
<iframe id="Iframepaso1" src="\pdf\test.pdf" runat="server" height="500" scrolling="AUTO" ></iframe>
```

The PDF has this line:

```
/Type /Action
/S /JavaScript
/JS (this.print\({bUI:true,bSilent:false,bShrinkToFit:true}\);)
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe>` has an attribute called `sandbox`. By default it will:

- block form submission
- block script execution
- disable APIs
- prevent links from targeting other browsing contexts
- prevent content from using plugins (through , , , or other)
- prevent the content to navigate its top-level browsing context
- block automatically triggered features (such as automatically playing a video or automatically focusing a form control)

You can remove specific restrictions by supplying special values to it.

Comment: thanks for answer but I just try that and sandbox blocks de PDF rendering and display nothing, there is no way to allow plugins in sandbox (I didn't find a way)

Comment: I'm sorry it did not help you, I too embed pdf files in my application and with `sandbox="allow_plugins"` it did work on firefox, now I tried opening it in chrome and it displays nothing as you said ;( Then if the pdf file is purely for show, you could first convert it to an image with a library and show that.